# I am still not able to run myworld program

Tags: x86

After installing everything (I think), I tried to run the program by select Nexus 5 API 21 x86 or Nexus 6 API 21, but none of them succeeded.

```
/Android Studio/bin/Studio.exe -> Run -> Select Nexus 5 API 21 x86 -> OK, got error:
/Android/SDK/tools/emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

/Android Studio/bin/Studio.exe -> Run -> Select Nexus 6 API 21 -> OK, got error:
/Android/SDK/tools/emulator.exe -avd Nexus_6_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 1536MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 1152MB.
Cannot set up guest memory 'android_arm': Invalid argument
Error accepting connection, aborting
```

Comment: Please update your post with  the source code of the program. Don't put stuff like **Edit** or **Update** in your revised question when you do. This site has edit history, those who need to see differences can get the information from there.

Comment: No program yet, sorry.